# how to send 2 arrays to $_SESSION?

Tags: php, session

Is it possible to send 2 one-line arrays with fetch_array to the $_session?

```
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
    if($row['user_type'] == 'admin'){
        $_SESSION['admin_name'] = $row['name'];
        header('location:admin_page.php');
```

I want to send `$row['name']` and `$row['email']`

to print through echo on the page.

```
<php echo ($_SESSION['admin_name']['name']); echo '<br>'; echo ($_SESSION['admin_name']['email']); ?>
```

some material on the subject

Comment: What does you stop from setting them? `$_SESSION['admin_name']['name'] = $row['name']; $_SESSION['admin_name']['email'] = $row['email'];`

Comment: `$_SESSION['admin_name'] = $row` should have this effect

Comment: Don't use `fetch_array()` if you don't need to. Either `fetch_row()` if you want numeric indexes, or `fetch_assoc()` if you want named indexes.

Comment: `$_SESSION['admin_name'] = ['name' => $row['name'], 'email' => $row['email']];`

Comment: $_SESSION['admin_name'] = $row has others arrays sendind i need filter only 2 arrays

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is a bit muddled, and suggests a few things you haven't fully understood.

- $_SESSION isn't something you "send to" - it's not a function, or a service. It's something you *store things in*; and more specifically, it's an array you can *assign things as items in*.
- $row['name'] and $row['email'] in your example are not "one-line arrays", they're single values, presumably strings. They happen to be stored *inside* an array, but that's irrelevant to what you do with them individually.
- $row *is* an array. If you want to, you can pass around and store that whole array, including everything inside it. In PHP an array can contain any kind of item, including other arrays.

With all that in mind, there's really nothing different about storing *two* things in $_SESSION compared to storing *one* thing - just assign them both with whatever key names you want:

```
$_SESSION['full_name'] = $row['name']
$_SESSION['email_address'] = $row['email'];
```

Or if you want to, you can store the whole array from the database in one key, and access the values inside it later:

```
$_SESSION['user'] = $row;
// ...
echo $_SESSION['user']['name'];
```

Or create a new array and store that:

```
$user = [
   'full_name' => $row['first_name'] . ' ' . $row['last_name'],
   'email' => $row['email'],
];
$_SESSION['user'] = $user;
```

The power of programming is that you can recombine the pieces into endless combinations, once you understand properly what each piece is.

Comment: I understand your point perfectly. however, I needed to send this data in a single session, it worked perfectly as Barmar reported

Comment: your 2 solution works perffetc for my use too, and  can store others values if necessary thx